# Why scanf doesn't work with spaces at the end of formal input?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying this:

```
    int M,N,K;
    printf("Enter (m,k,n) : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d ", &M, &K, &N);
    printf("\nDone?");
```

This is inside the main function. I need the program to read the three integers but when I run it, it just reads the three but doesn't go past the scanf, i.e. "Done?" isn't executed, as if it's still waiting for more input. If I remove the space after the last %d, it works fine. But why is that so?

Comment: Related: Don't use `scanf()` on potentially malformed (human) input. *Especially* not without checking the return value -- `M`, `K` and `N` might be uninitialized after your `scanf()`, and you wouldn't even know. Generally, it is preferable to read complete lines of input (`fgets()`) and then parse them in-memory. This way you can walk back in the input line; get better error handling out of e.g. `strtol()`, `strtod()`, or `strtok()`; and have the full input line available for meaningful error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I remove the space after the last %d, it works fine. But why is that so?

`" "` in `"%d %d %d "` directs `scanf()` to read, and not save, any number of whites-spaces including `'\n'`.

`scanf()` keeps consuming white-spaces until some non-white-space in encountered. [@user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788629/why-scanf-doesnt-work-with-spaces-at-the-end-of-formal-input/58788707#comment103859290_58788629)

`"%d %d %d "` obliges `scanf()` to not return until some non-white-space is read *after* the 3 numbers.

---

Tip: Avoid `scanf()`.  Use `fgets()` and then parse the *string*.  [@DevSolar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788629/why-scanf-doesnt-work-with-spaces-at-the-end-of-formal-input/58788707#comment103859610_58788629)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to take user inputs in multiple variables:

```
int M,N,K;
printf("Enter (m,k,n) : ");
scanf("%d", &M);
scanf("%d", &N);
scanf("%d", &K);
printf("\nDone?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the values separately. I don't think that scanf is intended to be used this way.
Also, what you're expecting putting a blank space at the end of scanf's string?
Try this:

```
scanf("%d", &M);
scanf("%d", &K);
scanf("%d", &N);
```

**EDIT:** I checked it out, and yeah, **you can** do that. **But** why you would want to do that way?  It will be harder to validate if the user input is incorrect, like with a blank space or a non intended char. 
You could read this as a full string with `fgets()` and the tokenize it with `strtok()`, if you're expecting everything in a single text line. 
Or simply read the values separately as showed.

Well, just my opinion, tho. If I'm wrong, please someone clarify me.